# Is there a better way of defining custom calendars?

Tags: algorithm, f#

I need to define custom calendars and, in particular, test a `DateTime` for being a holiday. My current code is shown below. Is there a more concise/better way of doing this, preferably without sacrificing performance?

```
let private isHoliday2011 (dt:DateTime) =
  match dt.DayOfWeek with
  | DayOfWeek.Saturday | DayOfWeek.Sunday ->
    match (dt.Month, dt.Day) with
    | (3,5) -> false
    | _ -> true
  | _ ->
    match dt.Month with
    | 1 ->
      match dt.Day with
      | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 10 -> true
      | _ -> false
    | 2 ->
      match dt.Day with
      | 23 -> true
      | _ -> false
    | 3 ->
      match dt.Day with
      | 7 | 8 -> true
      | _ -> false
    | 5 ->
      match dt.Day with
      | 2 | 9 -> true
      | _ -> false
    | 6 ->
      match dt.Day with
      | 13 -> true
      | _ -> false
    | 11 ->
      match dt.Day with
      | 4 -> true
      | _ -> false
    | _ -> false
```

Comment: I think your code is as good as it gets. All the other answers involving data structures sacrifice performance for no real gain in clarity. To tweak your code for clarity, you could try merging match statements, this should not have any performance effects, e.g. https://gist.github.com/3189294

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check for holidays repeatedly, I would go for [Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353619.aspx) and flatten pattern matching blocks for readability:

```
let holidays = set [ 1, 3; 1, 4; 1, 5; 1, 6; 1, 7; 1, 10 // month, day
                     2, 23
                     3, 7; 3, 8
                     5, 2; 5, 9
                     6, 13
                     11, 4
                    ]

let private isHoliday2011 (dt: DateTime) =
  match dt.DayOfWeek, dt.Month, dt.Day with
  | DayOfWeek.Saturday, m, d | DayOfWeek.Sunday, m, d -> m <> 3 || d <> 5    
  | _, m, d -> Set.contains (m, d) holidays
```

Comment: +1  `DayOfWeek.Saturday, m, d | DayOfWeek.Sunday, m, d` could be shortened (slightly) to `(DayOfWeek.Saturday | DayOfWeek.Sunday), m, d`. No need to bind `m` and `d` on both sides of `|`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the fastest, cleanest way you could check a large number of dates would be to memoize your date-checking function using a HashSet. Using `HashSet<T>` instead of the F# `set` is a better choice here because lookup is `O(1)` instead of `O(log n)` -- and you don't have to worry about mutability because the `HashSet` is never updated after it's created.

```
let isHoliday2011Memo =
    let holidays2011 =
        let jan1 = System.DateTime (2011, 1, 1)
        [| for i = 0 to 364 do
            yield jan1.AddDays <| float i |]
        |> Array.choose (fun day ->
            if isHoliday2011 day then
                Some day.DayOfYear
            else None)

    let holidayDaysOf2011 = System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<_> (holidays2011)

    fun (dt : DateTime) ->
        holidayDaysOf2011.Contains <| dt.DayOfYear
```

For even more speed, you could pre-compute the dates (using your function) -- and it means you don't need to include your date-computing function in your release code, because dates won't be calculated at run-time:

```
let isHoliday2011Precomputed =
    let holidayDaysOf2011 =
        System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<_> (
            [|1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 15; 16; 22; 23; 29; 30; 36; 37; 43; 44; 50;
            51; 54; 57; 58; 65; 66; 67; 71; 72; 78; 79; 85; 86; 92; 93; 99; 100; 106;
            107; 113; 114; 120; 121; 122; 127; 128; 129; 134; 135; 141; 142; 148; 149;
            155; 156; 162; 163; 164; 169; 170; 176; 177; 183; 184; 190; 191; 197; 198;
            204; 205; 211; 212; 218; 219; 225; 226; 232; 233; 239; 240; 246; 247; 253;
            254; 260; 261; 267; 268; 274; 275; 281; 282; 288; 289; 295; 296; 302; 303;
            308; 309; 310; 316; 317; 323; 324; 330; 331; 337; 338; 344; 345; 351; 352; 358;
            359; 365; |])

    fun (dt : DateTime) ->
        holidayDaysOf2011.Contains <| dt.DayOfYear
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using a list would be better - something like

```
let holidays = (1,3)::(1,4)::...
let isHoliday2011 (dt:DateTime) =
    let d,m = dt.Month, dt.Day
    holidays |> List.exists (fun (mm,dd) -> m=mm && d=dd)
```